# C# Rewrite textfile when listview is using textfile

Tags: c#

I've tried and tried but I can't figure out how I'm supposed to fix this.

I have a listView that reads data from a text file.

```
    private void Form3_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        listView1.View = View.Details;
        listView1.FullRowSelect = true;
        listView1.Columns.Add("Modell", 200);
        listView1.Columns.Add("Kw", 100);

        listView1.CheckBoxes = true;

        string RD_Paneler = "./Data/Paneler.txt";
        try
        {
            List<string> data = File.ReadAllLines(RD_Paneler).ToList();
            foreach (string d in data)
            {
                string[] items = d.Split(new char[] { ',' },
                       StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);
                listView1.Items.Add(new ListViewItem(items));
            }
        }
        catch
        {
        }
    }
```

`
So then I wanted the user to be able to press a "DELETE" button and all the checkboxed items would be deleted.

```
    private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        string exeFolder = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath);
        string settingFile = exeFolder + "/Data/Paneler.txt";

        var tempFile = Path.GetTempFileName();
        string alltext = File.ReadAllText(settingFile);

        foreach (ListViewItem item in listView1.Items)
        {
            var linesToKeep = File.ReadLines(settingFile).Where(l => l != item.Checked.ToString());
            if (item.Checked)
            {
                listView1.Items.Remove(item);
                File.WriteAllLines(tempFile, linesToKeep);
                File.Delete(settingFile); //Here is where to program crash happends.
                File.Move(tempFile, settingFile);

            }
        }
    }
```

The problem now is that when the program tries to delete the file and replace it with the new one the program crashes because the file it tries to delete is already in use because of the listview.

Comment: Hm, I wonder if ReadAllLnes really keeps alock on the file. Otoh you try to remove an element from a collection while you enumerate it, which usually causes a crash..

Answer (score 1):

**Here's few solutions -**

1. Use `File.ReadAllLines()` instead of `File.ReadLines()`. This should solve the primary problem you are having.
2. Since you have already read the `settingsFile` once in memory into `alltext`. Just use that to iterate over lines like `alltext.Split('\n')`. Even better IMO.

Hard to understand what your code is doing. Seems sketchy that in a `for` loop, you have set it up to write, delete, and move the same two files over and again?